# How do I resize images when the window is resized using JavaScript events?

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to resize a specific image in web-page using:

```js
 addEventListener('resize', function(evt){ 

var w = window.innerWidth
var element = querySelector(/*The ID of the element*/).style.width = w})
```

The problem is that the innerWidth/innerHeight properties are only used to **return** the dimensions of the element and can't be used in a statement, function, etc.

Anyone has an idea on how to do this? (Please try to find a solution that doesn't involve angular/react/JQuery because I'm still a beginner and have only worked with Vanilla JavaScript so far)

Comment: inside the the event listener set  your new width and height

Comment: how about using some responsive framework like Bootstrap, the result is much better

Answer (score 0):

Assign a width and height to the element (using javascript).

```
var w = window.innerWidth;
var element = document.getElementById("someid");
element.style.width = w * somepercent;
element.style.height = w * somepercent;
```

jQuery:

```
$("#someid").width(somewidth).height(someheight);
```

Comment: How exactly did you do it?

Comment: Exactly the way you mentioned above:             `window.addEventListener('resize', function (evt) {
            var w = window.Width;
            var Image = document.body.querySelector(".FlixItem_Images");
            Image.style.width = w * 50%;
        })`

Comment: Try giving it an id and getting the element using document.getElementById instead. Alternatively, use the jQuery method I added.